# Passing double quotes through PowerShell + WinRM

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, winrm, runspace

I am using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13284313/1118239) to execute remote code (MSI installs) on a server. Passing double quote through the script is just not working. I tried two variations as given below (#3 and #4) along with the outputs.

**Input #1 (Simple case to test double quotes in the command)**

```
powershell.exe -inputformat none -File client.ps1 -target 1.2.3.4 -port 5985 -password "pass" -username "user" -command "echo hello"
```

**Output (Works)**

```
hello
```

**Input #2 (Understandable, this won't work)**

```
powershell.exe -inputformat none -File client.ps1 -target 1.2.3.4 -port 5985 -password "pass" -username "user" -command "echo hello world"
```

**Output**

```
hello
world
```

**Input #3**

```
powershell.exe -inputformat none -File client.ps1 -target 1.2.3.4 -port 5985 -password "pass" -username "user" -command "echo `"hello world`""
```

**Output (What happened to the other word?)**

```
hello
```

**Input #4**

```
powershell.exe -inputformat none -File client.ps1 -target 1.2.3.4 -port 5985 -password "pass" -username "user" -command @'
>> echo "hello world"
>> '@
>>
```

**Output (Again, the 2nd word is missing)**

```
hello
```

If the echo works, I should be able to incorporate the changes to the MSI commands in the Runspace based usage I am doing.

---

MSI setup works fine if I use the following. Notice the single quotes.

```
msiexec /qn /i 'C:\setups\My Software.msi'
```

But, I need to pass public properties and MSI does not like single quote in it. Trying to run the following opens up the MSI arguments dialog.

```
msiexec /qn /i 'C:\setups\My Software.msi' MYPROP='My Value'
```

Running this from the local command prompt on the server works fine.

```
msiexec /qn /i "C:\setups\My Software.msi" MYPROP="My Value"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're calling this from cmd.exe, you'll have to escape the double quotes according to CMD's rules.

```
powershell.exe -command "echo \"hello world\""
```

#### Output

```
hello world
```

Personally, I would recommend avoiding passing the parameters in from the command line if at all possible. Maybe you could store the parameter values in a file (eg. serialized XML, JSON), and have the PowerShell script read the file?

Better yet, I would suggest doing any work with processes (eg. `msiexec.exe`) through the `Start-Process` cmdlet. That way, you can build up the value for the `-ArgumentList` parameter in a variable, and then be guaranteed that it will get passed through exactly the way you want it, and furthermore, you will not be restricted to the quoting rules of `cmd.exe`.

Consider the following:

```
$ArgumentList = '/package "c:\setups\My Software.msi" /passive /norestart /l*v "{0}\temp\Install My Software.log" MYPROP="My Value With Spaces"' -f $env:windir;
Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList $ArgumentList;
```

Comment: That did the trick. I modified the ScriptBlock of Invoke-Command to use the above. I kept placeholders for the dynamic items which I replace at runtime before passing onto Runspace.

Comment: Thanks, and +1. Your answer helped me solve my related question ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42065666/executing-ads-related-powershell-command-through-java-does-not-work-giving-2-dif

Answer (score 0):

Or you can encode your command as base64 strings to avoid any special characters from accidentally being interpreted, like encapsulated double quotes.

powershell.exe -EncodedCommand "ZQBjAGgAbwAgACIAaABlAGwAbABvACAAdwBvAHIAbABkACIA"

Result

```
hello world
```

ZQBjAGgAbwAgACIAaABlAGwAbABvACAAdwBvAHIAbABkACIA .... is base64 representation of this.  See how I didn't need to escape anything.

```
echo "hello world"
```