# executing ADS related Powershell command through Java does not work giving 2 different errors when using 2 different ways

Tags: java, powershell, active-directory, command, command-execution

I have been trying to execute a set of commands in a powershell session through java, with no luck yet. My aim is to search a computer object in AD with the domain = "domain.com".

I started with a single command. Unfortunately, the following command successfully runs in my powershell prompt:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -like "hostname" } –Server a.b.c.d:3268 -SearchBase 'DC=domain,DC=com' | FT DNSHostName
# hostname is actual hostname provided by user and accepted in argument of Java methods
# a.b.c.d is the IP-Address of my domain controller, and I'm trying to search a computer object in AD with the domain = "domain.com".
```

But, it produces different exceptions/errors with 2 different approaches.

1. I have tried the [basic way of executing powershell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545611/executing-powershell-commands-in-java-program), and then passing the command as argument to it. That did not work, resulted in different error described below.
2. Next, I tried using [jPowerShell library (profesorfalken)](https://github.com/profesorfalken/jPowerShell) with no luck again. Check the error in the last

---

**Code for first attempt:**

```
public String executeCommand(String hostname){
        String output = "";
        try{
//          String firstPartCommand = "Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -like (", secondPartCommand = ") } –Server a.b.c.d:3268 -SearchBase 'DC=domain,DC=com' | FT DNSHostName"; 
            String firstPartCommand = "Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -like \""+hostname+"\" } –Server a.b.c.d:3268 -SearchBase \'DC=domain,DC=com\' | FT DNSHostName"; 

            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            String[] cmds = new String[]{
                "powershell.exe", firstPartCommand.trim()
            };
            System.out.println(firstPartCommand);

            Process pr = rt.exec(cmds);
            pr.getOutputStream().close();
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getErrorStream()));

            System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
            String s = null;
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s+" -> OUTPUT");
            output+=s;
            //displayTF.setText(s);
            }
            stdInput.close();
            System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s+" -> ERROR");
            }
            stdError.close();
            return output;
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
            output = "Some exception occured, SORRY!";
            return output;
        }
    }
```

Output:

> Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -like "hostname" } –Server
>   a.b.c.d:3268 -SearchBase 'DC=domain,DC=com' | FT DNSHostName
>
> Here is the standard output of the command:
>
> Here is the standard error of the command (if any):
>
> Get-ADComputer : Error parsing query: ' Name -like hostname' Error
>   Message: 'syntax error' at position: '13'. -> ERROR At line:1 char:1
>   -> ERROR
>   + Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -like hostname} -Server a.b.c.d ... -> ERROR
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   -> ERROR
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ADFilterParsingException -> ERROR
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Micr
>   -> ERROR    osoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer -> ERROR   -> ERROR

---

**Code for second attempt:**

```
public String execute(String hostname){
        String output = "";
        PowerShell powershell = null;
        try{            
            powershell = PowerShell.openSession();
//            String cmd = "$variable = \""+hostname+"\"";
//            //Execute a command in PowerShell session
//            PowerShellResponse response = powershell.executeCommand(cmd);
//            //Print results
//            System.out.println("Variable Initialisation:" + response.getCommandOutput());
            String firstPartCommand = "Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -like \"", secondPartCommand = "\" } –Server 10.0.239.236:3268 -SearchBase 'DC=AD,DC=SBI' | FT DNSHostName"; 
            String finalCommand = firstPartCommand+hostname+secondPartCommand;
            System.out.println(finalCommand);
            PowerShellResponse response = powershell.executeCommand(finalCommand);
            //PowerShellResponse response = powershell.executeCommand("Get-Process powershell -FileVersionInfo");
            output = response.getCommandOutput();
            System.out.println("Search result: "+hostname+"\n" + output);
            return output;
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            return "Failed!";
        }
        finally {
       //Always close PowerShell session to free resources.
            if (powershell != null)
                powershell.close();
        }
    }
```

Output:

> Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -like "hostname" } –Server
>   a.b.c.d:3268 -SearchBase 'DC=domain,DC=com' | FT DNSHostName
>
> Search result: hostname
>
> Get-ADComputer : A positional parameter cannot be
>   found that accepts argument '–Server'. At line:1 char:1
>   + Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -like "hostname" } –Server a.b.c.d ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer

---

From what I've searched and understood, the hostname which is passed to the Java method is not getting treated as a string in the powershell. These errors are pertaining to powershell, which I'm not much experienced with.

---

**EDIT:** After [Mathias R. Jessen's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) reply, I'm not getting any error in the 2nd case; but, it seems the library itself is not correct up to the mark.

So, talking about the first method, I'm getting the error as mentioned in the first case. I want to get on with the first method only!

I have, almost, lost my faith in the external jPowershell JAR. I'm not getting the error in the 2nd output; but, neither getting the output. It behaves as if there is no output of the command!

Request to kindly help me solve this problem!

Comment: You have an em-dash in your second example - replace `–Server` with `-Server`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Thanks, now I'm not getting the error in the 2nd output; but, neither getting the output. It behaves as if there is no output of the command!
Also, can you help you with why the first code is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling for almost 3 days, I found the problem to be in the command string, as expected.

The correct command (for the first case) should be:

```
String firstPartCommand = "Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -eq \'"+hostname+"\' } 
-Server a.b.c.d:3268 -SearchBase \'DC=domain,DC=com\' | Select DNSHostName";
```

The correct command (for the second case) should be:

```
String firstPartCommand = "Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -eq \'", 
secondPartCommand = "\' }  -Server a.b.c.d:3268 -SearchBase \'DC=domain,DC=com\' |
 Select DNSHostName";
```

Comment: But, my personal suggestion would be to avoid 2nd method as it more frequently results in `Feb 08, 2017 3:04:34 PM com.profesorfalken.jpowershell.PowerShell waitUntilClose

SEVERE: Unexpected error when closing PowerShell: TIMEOUT!`