# Lost rdp access to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, rdp

I changed the firewall (on windows server ) of an Amazon EC2 instance to accept the Remote Desktop connections only for a specific IP address .

Once changes are done , i lost connection and i am no longer able to access the instance .

my question is :

is there a way to access this instance again or is it completely lost ?

Comment: Unless you have some other means of being able to remotely configure the box, it's gone. If the box was domain joined, you might be able to use group policy to change the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use Windows Remote Management (WinRM) to open a console to the machine and change the firewall setting from the command line.

WinRM uses port 5985 and it is on by default on some windows images on EC2 (not all of them). Try opening port 5985 in your security group and log in with a Powershell client.

There are some instructions on how to use powershell for WinRM here: [How to programmatically/remotely execute a program in EC2 Windows instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237083/how-to-programmatically-remotely-execute-a-program-in-ec2-windows-instance/13284313#13284313)

You can run the steps in the script manually.