# Alternatives for PsExec which works in standard user

Tags: psexec, command-line-tool, remote-execution

I am using psexec to execute commands on remote server. Here is my command,

```
PsExec.exe" -u user \\server -h run.bat
```

I am entering the password manually. here I am using standard user account due to security issues. When I run the command I am getting the error,

```
"Make sure that the default admin$ share is enabled"
```

I read [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/280482/how-to-use-psexec-without-admin-privileges-on-target-machine) that it cannot be done without admin privileges. 
But when I test the same command in LAN it works in standard user.

How it works in LAN not in Remote server ?

Is there any alternative tools which will work in standard user ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate tool, you can use Powershell and WinRM. Powershell allows you to execute a command, or an interactive session, on the remote windows server.

An example of executing a command is available here:
[How to programmatically/remotely execute a program in EC2 Windows instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237083/how-to-programmatically-remotely-execute-a-program-in-ec2-windows-instance/13284313#13284313)

If you need an interactive session, look at the Powershll command 'Enter-PSSession': https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849707.aspx

Comment: whether the method suggested will work, if I use non-admin credentials of remote server ?

Comment: It should. There is some initial setup work you need to do on the client that requires admin, but that is a one-time setup, and only in the client. As long as the remote system has been configured to allow WinRM, you should be able to log in with any user that is valid on that system